# ActiveMQ : how to fork-join? Ie. how to emit one message when all subtasks are done

Tags: java, parallel-processing, jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer

imagine you have some task structure of

```
Task1
Task2: 1 million separate independent Subtask[i] that can run concurrently
Task3: must run once after ALL Task2 subtasks have completed
```

And all of Task1, Subtask[i] and Task3 are represented by MQ messages.
How can this be solved on an ActiveMQ? Especially the triggering of a Task3 message once all subtasks are complete.

I know, it's not a queueing problem, it's a fork-join problem. Lets say the environment dictates you must use an ActiveMQ for it.

Using ActiveMQ features, dynamic queues and consumers, stuff like that, is allowed. Using external counters, like a database row representing Task2's progress, is not allowed.

Comment: This question is too vague. It will elicit discussion and opinion-based answers rather than fact-based answers therefore it is off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Without more details- specifically around exception handling this feels more like an academic exercise over a real world scenario. For example-- is the total number of tasks known upfront-- if not, is there a message that indicates the task group has all been sent? What should the behavior be if one or more messages never arrive? Is this processed over a single server or multiple servers?

Comment: It's a question on "how can you solve this the MQ way", Ie. what are the best practices, if there are any (but my bet is on there aren't, because ActiveMQ is a queue and not a fork-join pool, and no one wants to do something like this). Yes, the number of subtasks is known when Task2's processing starts. Single/multi server: one ActiveMQ server, and no restrictions where/how many consumer processes are running.

Comment: None of the adhoc ideas work out in the end. If you're using a database row, to keep track of how many Subtask[i] -s have completed for Task2, then you're not solving things the MQ way. Subtask consumer threads can live on multiple servers of course, that's the whole point of scaling. You can experiment with dynamically created Task2-specific queues, and dynamically add consumers, but it starts to get very hacky once the topic of error recovery/transactionality come into the picture. Also you can't have a long-lived session for babysitting Task2's completion. So nothing really works.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden in this fork-join problem is a state management and observability challenge. Since the database is ruled out, you have to rely on something in-memory or on-queue.

1. Create a unique id for the task run -- something short, but with enough space to not collide like an airplane locator code-- ie. 34FDSX
2. Send all messages for the task to a queue://TASK.34FDSX.DATA
3. Send a control message to queue://TASK.34FDSX.CONTROL that contains the task id and expected total # of messages (including each messageId would be helpful too)
4. When consumers from queue://TASK.34FDSX.DATA complete their work, they should send a 'done' message to queue://TASK.34FDSX.DONE queue with their messageId or some identifier.

The consumers for the .CONTROL queue and the .DONE queue should be the same process and can track the expected and total completed tasks. Once everything is completed, he can fire the event to trigger Task #3.

This approach provides everything as 'online', and you can also timeout the .CONTROL and .DONE reader if too much time passes before the task completes.

Queue deletion can be done using ActiveMQ destination GC, or as a clean-up step in the .CONTROL/.DONE reader during the occurances when everything completes successfully.

Advantages:

- No infinite blocking consumers
- No infinite open transactions
- State of the TASK is online and observable via the presence of queues and queue metrics-- queue size, enqueue count, dequeue count
- The entire solution can be multi-threaded and the only requirement is that for a given task the .CONTROL/.DONE listener is the same consumer, but multiple tasks can have individual .CONTROL/.DONE listeners to scale.

Comment: Yes, this is a good one. My only concern is resource leaks when creating/destroying TASK.<airplane_code> queues,  for eg. hundreds of airplanes a day, 24/7. It doesn't sound like something many activemq users do. But agreed, this is a production-ready setup.

Comment: This pattern is used a lot!! -- semi-temporary queues. The Control code can delete the queues when a successful process is completed-- leaving the queues for unsuccessful allows for inspection. Alternatively, you can use "ActiveMQ Destination Garbage Collection" for queue deletion when there is no activity.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to tell an activemq connection that "from a queue (eg. CounterQueue) let me consume the msg that matches a criteria  (eg. CounterMsg.airplane==34FDSX)"? I could have nice static queues, nice static spring beans/consumers.  And transactionally: consume a SubtaskDone message, consume the CounterMsg for 34FDSX, either resubmit a new CounterMsg with payload i+1. Or if the target is reached, fire Task3.  Prerequisite is that somehow I can consume the airplane's CounterMsg in a  targeted way.

Answer (score 0):

The question here is a bit vague so my answer will have to be a bit vague as well.

Each of the million independent subtasks for "Task 2" can be represented by a single message. All these messages can be in the same queue. You can spin up as many consumers as you want and process all these messages (i.e. perform all the subtasks). Just ensure that these consumers either use client-acknowledge mode or a transacted session so that the message is not removed from the queue until they are done processing the message. Once there are no more messages in the queue then you know "Task 2" is done.

To detect when the queue is empty you can have a "special" consumer on the queue that periodically opens a transacted session and tries to consume a message from the queue. If the consumer receives a message then you can rollback the transacted session to put the message back on the queue and you know that the queue is not empty (i.e. "Task 2" is not done). If the consumer *doesn't* receive a message then you know the queue is empty and you can send another message indicating this. You could launch this special consumer as part of "Task 2" after all the messages for the subtasks have been sent to avoid detecting an empty queue prematurely.

To be clear, this is a *simple* solution. You could certainly add more complexity depending on your requirements, but your question just outlined the basic problem so it's unclear what other requirements you have (if any).

Comment: "If the <special> consumer doesn't receive" problem is this doesn't answer the question of "are all subtasks are done". Maybe Task2 (subtask producer) is not fast enough and the subtask queue is drained before all tasks have been submitted. 2nd problem: not-getting a message can also mean one "normal" subtask consumer is still working on the last subtask message. So strictly speaking if "special" consumer kicks off a Task3 message there's a potential race condition.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. In short, don't ack a message until the work is done, and don't start the special consumer until all the subtask messages are sent.